# Inserting rows in a table from another table using a third table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, stored-procedures, join

I have 3 tables in my database as shown below:
[image]

I want to insert data in `RESULT` table from `Infos` table. And only those rows are inserted that are listed in `Picker` table. But since `InfoID` column of `Result` table is a primary key, so it will restrict already existed `InfoID` to be reinserted again. And `Picker` table's 'InfoIDs' can have repeated values. `Picker` table is actually a temporary table created in a stored procedure.

I am not so pro in making join queries, so I took help of some SO questions and developed following query:

```
INSERT INTO @Result([INFOID],[VALUE],[PROCESSED]) (SELECT T1.Id,
      CASE 
         WHEN T1.Value1 = '-1' THEN T1.Value2
         ELSE T1.Value1
      END, 0 
    FROM [Infos] T1 LEFT JOIN (SELECT [InfoIDs] FROM Picker AS A1 WHERE (NOT EXISTS (SELECT [INFOID] FROM @Result AS A2 WHERE A1.[InfoIDs] != A2.[INFOID]))) T2 ON T1.Id = T2.InfoIDs)
```

But the problem is that I am getting only one row in output of `Result` table. Please tell me what's wrong with my query?

**UPDATE**

Expected Result:

[image]

Comment: What would be your expected rseult?

Comment: I tested your code and it is giving desired result. Check this sql fiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/36a2d/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I figured out what was actually going wrong:

```
INSERT INTO @Result([INFOID],[VALUE],[PROCESSED]) (SELECT T1.Id,
      CASE 
         WHEN T1.Value1 = '-1' THEN T1.Value2
         ELSE T1.Value1
      END, 0 
    FROM [Infos] T1 INNER JOIN (SELECT [InfoIDs] FROM Picker AS A1 WHERE (NOT EXISTS (SELECT [INFOID] FROM @Result AS A2 WHERE A1.[InfoIDs] = A2.[INFOID]))) T2 ON T1.Id = T2.InfoIDs)
```

I used `INNER JOIN` and in `A1.[InfoIDs != A2.[INFOID]` condition I added `=` instead of `!=`.

I combined all the solutions and hints suggested by the responders of this question and came up with this solution. Thank you everyone. :)

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested this but it should work. First you get the distinct values from Infos and then you merge them into the result table. If the InfoID exists already in result, then update the value. If it doesn't exist then add it. If you don't want to update existing records and only add new ones, remove the `WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE`block, up to but excluding `WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN UPDATE`

```
MERGE INTO 
    Result
USING
    (SELECT
        DistinctInfos.ID,
        CASE WHEN DistinctInfos.Value1= -1 THEN DistinctInfos.Value2 ELSE DistinctInfos.Value1 END ValueToInsert
    FROM
        (SELECT
            Infos.ID,
            MAX(Infos.Value1) Value1,
            MAX(Infos.Value2) Value2
        FROM
            Infos
            INNER JOIN Picker ON Infos.ID = Picker.InfoIDs
        GROUP BY 
            Infos.ID
        ) DistinctInfos
    )InfosToBeInserted
ON
    (Result.InfoID = InfosToBeInserted.ID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
    SET Result.Value = InfosToBeInserted.ValueToInsert
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT
    (
        InfoID,
        Result,
        Processed
    )
    VALUES
    (
        InfosToBeInserted.ID,
        InfosToBeInserted.ValueToInsert,
        0
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

Can we do something like:

```
INSERT INTO @Result(InfoID, Value, Processed)
(
    SELECT DISTINCT
        inf.Id,
        CASE WHEN inf.Value1 = '-1' THEN inf.Value2 ELSE inf.Value1 END,
        0 
    FROM Infos inf
    INNER JOIN Picker pic ON inf.Id = pic.InfoIDs
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @Result res WHERE res.InfoID = pic.InfoIDs)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need this query:

```
INSERT INTO @Result
(SELECT ID, 
    CASE 
         WHEN i.Value1 = '-1' THEN i.Value2
         ELSE i.Value1
      END
Value1, 0
FROM Infos i
WHERE i.ID In (SELECT InfoIDs FROM Picker)
  AND NOT i.ID IN (SELECT InfoID FROM @Result))
```